# Windows 8.1 is not booting with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I have an Asus Q200E 64 bit laptop. I had a pre-installed Windows 8.0 which I updated to Windows 8.1. I recently updated Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. After updating ubuntu, I cannot boot to Windows any more. The grub has the option to choose Windows but when I choose that a blank screen shows up and stays forever.

Before this happened, I used to choose the operating systems from the BIOS settings. I go to the boot options in BIOS settings and I could choose what operating system I want to use from there. It still showing I have both of the operating systems like before but Windows is not running any more. I am wondering if anybody knows the solution of it. Any useful help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the Ubuntu repair CD. Not sure if your laptop has a CD drive as many these days do not ship with Optical Drive.  You can also install the Repair utility inside Ubuntu, but I've not used it in that way.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It has a "Repair MBR" function that may be useful to solve your issue.

Found this info as well ...

> After you’ve got a live CD image, you can use the Startup Disk Creator
>   tool included with Ubuntu to create a bootable USB drive from it. Just
>   launch the Startup Disk Creator application from the dash and specify
>   your new ISO file as the source disk image.
>   From: http://www.howtogeek.com/109736/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a CD drive. 

I have already installed the Boot-Repair for Ubuntu. But the "Repair MBR" function is disabled.

Comment: Are you able to create a Live USB of boot repair then?  That might be your best bet. It kind-of makes sense that while booted into Ubuntu OS, the OS cannot get to the windows MBR, but that's a guess.

Comment: Updated original answer to include link to creating LIVE USB. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Another thing to try (if the computer has Secure Boot) is to check whether or not this is switched on.  As you boot up, get to the Boot Options page. Sometimes, Windows refuses to boot unless in Secure Mode, which could play havoc in trying to boot into Ubuntu at a later time.

Comment: @Adam T:You should report your case immediately if Windows 8 refuses to boot in unrestricted boot and/or custom mode. It is OEM certification violation.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney Thanks, but my system is ok, just reflecting based on my own experiences from a while back.  Machine works fine in unrestricted (non-secure boot). I was commenting in order to possibly assist the author of the original question.